# Mapping observableArray to Multiple SELECT based off another json array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, knockout.js

3I use jquery to $.getJSON and populate a SELECT dropdown with this information (the `<OPTION>`s value is the `ItemID`, and the text is the `DisplayName`):

```
//$.getJSON and populate <SELECT> options with this info
{"ItemOptions": [
 {"ItemID" : 1, "DisplayName": "Apples"},
 {"ItemID" : 2, "DisplayName": "Bananas"},
 {"ItemID" : 3, "DisplayName": "Oranges"},
 {"ItemID" : 4, "DisplayName": "Grapes"},
 {"ItemID" : 5, "DisplayName": "Carrots"},
 {"ItemID" : 6, "DisplayName": "Crushed Dreams"}
]}
```

Later on in the code, I get a shipment "manifest", which contains some information, of which includes a list of things that were shipped, it looks like this:

```
//manifest
{
    "LocationSource"    : "Dallas",
    "LocationDestination"   : "New York",
    "Items" : [
        {"ItemID" : 2},
        {"ItemID" : 3},
        {"ItemID" : 6}
    ],
    "Status" : "In Transit"
}
// then ko.mapping.toJS(manifest) and 
// ko.applyBindings(manifest) is done in javascript.
```

You'll notice that the Items array in the manifest have `ItemID` - which match up to the `ItemID` I've populated the SELECT with.

I use Knockout's mapping plugin -- and just `ko.mapping.fromJS(manifest)` -- works great.   The INPUTs and SPANs and such where I map LocationSource, Status and the like are doing great.

My problem is that I want that SELECT to be a multiple, and representative of my Items in my manifest (the ability to add/remove them).  HTML is like:

```
<input data-bind="value: LocationSource"/>
<input data-bind="value: LocationDestination"/>
<select multiple="multiple" data-bind="value: Items"></select>   // this thing
```

or

```
<select multiple="multiple" data-bind="value: Items().ItemID"></select>
```

doesn't seem to be cutting it for me, and I can't seem to figure out how to get it to work right (it appears that the ko.mapping *is* setting the `Items` to an array, but any time I make selections in the SELECT box, it explodes (either stays as it was when initialized, or gets changed from a function to a straight value, depending on how I tinker in code).

Essentially, my question is this:

I have a list of "things".    They have IDs that match to an array in my manifest that is ko.mapped (and supposedly an .observableArray for that property).   How can I add or remove from my `Items` based off that list of "things" (ItemOptions) -- so that when I push the `ko.map.toJS(manifest)` back up to the server, my Items array will still be a list of ItemIDs representative of what I chose in the SELECT.

edit:   I've looked at adding the entire list as something like .AllItems to the manifest, like they show in the [Knockout examples](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=collections) (self.AvailableMeals), but that's really not what I want -- nor do I want that entire list pushed back to the server when I map.toJS and $.post it back.

**UPDATE**

```
self.AllItems = ItemOptions;                                    //doesn't need to change, dont obvserable it, right?
self.Items = ko.observableArray(model.Items);
```

Then, in the HTML I have:

```
<select data-bind="options: AllItems,  optionsText: 'DisplayName', selectedOptions: Items" size="15" multiple="true"></select>
```

This is getting me there, very close.   It's manipulating the manifest like I expect it to -- the only issue now is that when I first load the manifest and apply bindings, the SELECT doesn't autoselect the Items that are in the manifest.  I *suspect* this is because the Items array entry and the ItemOptions entry aren't identical?   They both have ItemID, but one has DisplayName, and the other doesn't.

**UPDATE 2**

Added a jsfiddle:    It will demonstrate that it works, but doesn't select the initial load:

http://jsfiddle.net/85Pvz/1

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly you want to use the [selectedOptions binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/selectedOptions-binding.html)?

so you'd have something like:

```
 <select data-bind="options: ItemOptions, selectedOptions: (manifest.)Items, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'id'" size="5" multiple="true"></select>
```

and for your javascript something like:

```
ItemOptions = [
    {name: "opt1", id: 1},
    {name: "opt2", id: 2},
    {name: "opt3", id: 3},
    {name: "opt4", id: 4} 
]
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/8Hj6w/)

Comment: This is the right path.  I'm getting there, except my Items in my manifest only have a numeric array, without the ItemID label - when I start clicking around.   It also doesn't have them preselected.  I *suspect* it's because what's in Items and what's in ItemOptions are identically flavored arrays?

Comment: If you leave out the `optionsValue` parameter you get the entire object, [see here](http://jsfiddle.net/8Hj6w/1/)

Comment: I was able to do that - and that works great, it gives me the labels like I wish.   Now my only problem is when I am initially loading the manifest (applying the bindings), the SELECT isn't :selected'ing the choices that are in the manifest (probably because they're not similar arrays, one just has ItemID the other has ItemID and DisplayName).   In short, in my example above -- items 2,3,6 are not selected in the SELECT.    Any ideas?

Comment: I've updated my original post up top to reflect where it is at now, working but not selecting the items initially when loading and applying bindings.   If I click in the SELECT, it populates the Items right, but on that initial load, it's not selecting what it already has.

Comment: To make it easier to get where I'm going with this, I've created a js fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/85Pvz/

Comment: The thing is, in javascript, object {"ItemId":1, "DisplayName": "Apples"} != object {"ItemID":1, "DisplayName": "Apples"}. That's why you want to specifiy the optionsValue parameter, because then you've given knockoutjs a "key" to compare on for equality. That way you can set self.SelectedItems([1,2,3]) and it will select those in the multi-select. But if you really need to have your id as objects, you could add a subscriptions to `SelectedItems`, and have that one update the `Items` object, [like so](http://jsfiddle.net/7REQD/3/)

Comment: It *almost* looks like I can use the ko.mapping plugin and maybe use the keys option 

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html#example_using_komapping

...but then trying to create an .AllItems property in a ko.mapping automated mapping makes mmy head swim.

I can't thank you enough for the help you've provided so far.